# How can I delay running code on the UI thread in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, wait

So I have a BackgroundWorker that does some stuff, then when it completes, `RunWorkerCompleted` has to update an ObjectListView.

Problem is, the user could be editing a cell in the ObjectListView. Trying to update it during cell editing results in absolute carnage, so i don't want to let `RunWorkerCompleted` do it's thing unless the user is not editing (i.e. `ObjectListView.IsCellEditing` is false).

What's the best way to do this?

I mean I could just set a timer to check `IsCellEditing` is false, but that seems a bit like a hammer to crack a nut and feels a bit dirty somehow.

Comment: Does ObjectListView provide any relevant events? There is no global concept of “user is not interacting”. (Also, consider that the value-to-update may be stale when the user completes the edit.)

Comment: Is it better to discard the user's input at a later time instead of immediately?

Comment: @user2864740 It has a `CellEditFinished` event. I see what you're getting at, I could set a bool somewhere to tell `CellEditFinished` to check whether the OLV needs to be updated and do it from there instead.

Comment: @ThomasWeller wait, what? Why would I want to discard the user's input?

Comment: @JezClark because you will do that when `RunWorkerCompleted` will update the ObjectListView, won't you ?

Comment: @Cid no. User input is kept, it's other values in the OLV that get updated. To flesh this out a bit: user inputs a value, backgroundworker calculates some other values based on that, `RunWorkerCompleted` updates the OLV to show those values. At no point does it do anything to the user's input. What I'm trying to avoid is all hell breaking loose when the OLV gets updated - e.g. if the user is still editing a cell while I try and update the OLV, the cell they are editing may get filtered out and then OLV throws exceptions around all over the place.

Comment: Why not greying out the OLV while the worker is running, to prevent the user to change things ?

Comment: @Cid because the calculation takes too long, user wants to be able to edit stuff while waiting for the calculation to complete.

Comment: why not break up the processing that needs to happen after the background processor finishes... break it out into a separate function. Then have that background process check if a cell is being edited. if not... immediately call that new function. If a cell is being edited... then set a flag that is checked when the cell is finished being edited that kicks that post processing off if/when needed. clear the flag for the next time around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `OnCellEditFinishing` event to know when editing has completed.

So if `IsCellEditing` is `true`, then store the result of the calculation somewhere and in your `OnCellEditFinishing` handler, check for data that needs to be updated and make the update.

Comment: This is kinda what I ended up doing, I (as I suggested in my own comment further up) made `CellEditFinished` check a flag to see if the OLV needed to be updated. It seems to work quite neatly and required very little extra code.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your code where your background process CAN be paused safely. You can add as many points as you like.

```
bw.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite);
```

And when you want it to trigger pauses at those points from your main thread... like when they begin editing a cell... use:

```
bw.Reset();
```

And to resume:

```
bw.Set();
```